# How can I save coordinates to a text file?

Tags: objective-c

I would like the latitude/longitude coordinates to be saved in a text file called "Location.txt" (this file would first have to be created) in "var/mobile/Documents" folder each time I push the "Get My Location" button, each time overwriting the old coordinates. Is this possible? Could someone please give me example of how this can be done. Thanks.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController {
CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)getCurrentLocation:(id)sender {
locationManager.delegate = (id)self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                           initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[errorAlert show];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

if (currentLocation != nil) {
    _LongitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    _LatitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
}

// Stop Location Manager
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just create an NSString that your app knows how to read. E.g:

```
NSString *newLocString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f",currentLocation.coordinate.longitude, currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
NSString *path = //File Path.txt
NSError *error = nil;
// Save string and check for error
if (![newLocStrin writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"An Error occurred: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}
```

Then read it like this:

```
NSString *path = //File Path.txt
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *location = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path usedEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
if (!location) {
    NSLog(@"Error reading location file: %@", error.localizedDescription);
} 
else {
    // Have read the string so now format it back
    NSString *longitude = nil;
    NSString *latitude = nil;
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:location];
    [scanner scanUpToString:@"," intoString:&longitide];
    latitude = [location stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,",longitude] withString:@""];
   NSLog(@"Location equals %f,%f", longitude.floatValue, latitude.floatValue);
}
```

It might be easier to use an NSDictionary and save that either to the NSUserDefaults or as a .plist file:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"Longitude":@(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude), @"Latitude":@(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)};
```

Then to user defaults:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dict forKey:@"Location"];
// To read...
NSDictionary *locDict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Location"];
float longitude = [[locDict objectForKey:@"Longitude"] floatValue];
// e.t.c
```

To write to a .plist file use NSDictionary's `writeToFile: atomically:` methods similar to NSString's method above.

Hope this is enough to get the job done!

EDIT: all of the file writing methods overwrite old versions of the file.

EDIT 2: Saving the plist file in your code:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

if (currentLocation != nil) {
    _LongitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    _LatitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    NSDictionary *locDict = @{@"Long":@(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude),@"Lat":@(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)};
    // Probably want to save the file in the Application Support directory
    NSString *path = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"location.plist"];
    if (![locDict writeToFile:path atomically:YES]) {
        NSLog(@"An error occurred.");
    }
    // Or save to NSUserDefaults
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefualts] setObject:locDict forKey:@"Location"];
}

// Stop Location Manager
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried the NSDictionary way but get error with this libel float long = [[locDict objectForKey:@"Longitude"] floatValue]; errors are "Expected identifier or '('" and 'long float' is invalid. I am new to objective-c & not even sure where I put this in my file! Would it be too much to ask you to add the code in my code posted above? If no it's ok, thanks pal. PS. Plist file method if it's easier if fine.

Comment: In your code you would want to save it in `locationManager: didUpdateToLocation: fromLocation:` method. I'll update my answer for saving to .plist.

Comment: Yes, I found a tutorial on youtube, found out I had to use locationManager. Sorry for being such a newb pal. Thanks again! I wait for your update. ;)

Comment: No probs. My fault for the error you are getting. You can't use long as a variable name as it defines a variable type e.g. `unsigned long x = 200000000;` So just change the var from long to longitude or something.

Comment: Thanks pal, stupid question, where is the Application Support directory, all seems to be good now but can't find the directory to chaco if the file exists LOL.. If I want to save it to var/mobile/Documents, how to change it? Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming this is an iOS app. If so the application support directory is a folder in your app's sandbox, so no you can't just open it up and look inside. If it's OS X and your app isn't a sandboxed app then the file is in the Users/Me/Library/ApplicationSupport/AppName/location.plist

Comment: If your app is sandboxed then the file will be in the Users/Me/Library/Containers/MyAppContainer/Data/Library/ApplicationSupport/location.plist. Just change the path variable to `= @"var/mobile/Documents/location.plist"` if you want to change the file save location.